# A singular verb comes after "any of [plural noun]", or a plural one?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, determiners, quantifiers

In some English text it is said that we should use a singular verb in the following example:

- Any of the computers **needs** updating.

However, it is said that in the following examples we should use plural verbs:

- **Do** any of the computers **need** updating?
- Not any of the computers **need** updating.

I wonder why we use the verb (*need*) with different number in the above examples while in all of them the verbs follow the same phrase "*any of the computers*"?

Comment: Please improve your question. "Any of the computers needs updating" makes no sense, but it is the basis of your question. It sounds as if it might be part of a longer sentence. If it is, please post the rest.

Comment: "In some English text it is said...."  Whenever you are referencing a source you must (1) cite the source (tell us the name of the English text)" and (2) Quote the full explanation from the source.  Your example "Any of the computers needs updating." is ungrammatical and no good English text would give this example in this form.

Comment: I've just been through some of your past questions and you quote "some book" quite often.  Lots of the examples you quote from this unknown book are wrong.  So please put the book in the bin and find a better book.

Comment: @JamesK Why is that sentence ungrammatical?

Answer (score 1):

We do this with all sorts of verbs.

> I get hungry often

> He gets hungry often

> They get hungry often

Usually we conjugate verbs with singular subjects with an `s`.

So:

> One of the computers needs updating

> All of the computers need updating

> None of the computers need updating

Note: "Any of the computers needs updating" sounds very awkward. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say here. Also, "not any" is almost always replaced with "none".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain why we have to use plural verbs in "Do any of the computers need updating?" and "Not any of the computers need updating." ?

Comment: You're not using "plural verbs" here, they don't have a `s`.